# My java program stops working correctly unexpectedly

Tags: java, multithreading, graphics

I am programming a basic java game, but I am having an issue.
Everytime that I try it out, if I wait just for 10 seconds, the program stops working correctly. I've made a class called `Drawable`, which has a `paint` function. This `paint` function paints a rectangle on a certain area(given on the constructor).
And I have a thread that iterates over all drawables in an arraylist(added randomly, with another thread), and just substracts 1 to their `x`. When it stops working correctly, the character can jump and does all animations, but the drawables stop moving. At first I thought this might have given a `ConcurrentModificationException` error, but it didn't print it on the console.
So right now I don't really know what to do.
Here I add the `Drawables`:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (Game.isPlayingGame) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*2000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            obstacles.add(new Drawable(
                 Constants.WIDTH,
                 (int) (Constants.HEIGHT / 2),
                 Constants.WIDTH - 100, 
                 (int) (Constants.HEIGHT / 2) - 100, 
                 Color.BLUE));
        }
    }
});
t2.start();
```

Here I move the `Drawables`:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {  
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (Game.isPlayingGame) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (Drawable d : obstacles) {
                d.x -= 1;
                d.x2 -= 1;
                if (d.x2 < 0) {
                    obstacles.remove(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

paint method:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    floor.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform ant = g2d.getTransform();
    g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(rotation), 
               character.x - Constants.characterSize / 2, 
               character.y - Constants.characterSize / 2);
    character.paint(g);
    g2d.setTransform(ant);
    for (Drawable d : obstacles) {
        d.paint(g);
        System.out.println(rotation_down);
        if (!rotation_down) {
            if (!character.onCollision(floor)) {
                character.y += (int) gravityAccel; // gravity
                character.y2 += (int) gravityAccel; // gravity
                gravityAccel += 0.1;
            } else {
                Screen.canJump = true;
                gravityAccel = 0;
            }
        }

    }
    repaint();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I also have a `Constants` class that stores basically the screen dimensions(`WIDTH` and `HEIGHT`)

Comment: Hint: you are posting a lot of code here; and then this is about multi-threading. So dont be surprised if not too many people really read all of that to find potential bugs in your code. In essence: try if you can reduce this to a **minimal** example. As a first starter; you want to read about the **Event dispatcher thread** and what happens when you do the wrong things with that (for example that can freeze UIs easily and make them un-responsive).

Comment: OK, I'll try to minimize it

Comment: What is type of obstacles? What is Drawable? In one of the threads you directly update d.x and dx2, which, I assume, are used in Drawable.paint(). How did you synchronize those? It is possible that Drawable.paint() is called between d.x -= 1 and d.x2-=1 calls, or after d.x2-=1 call but before d is removed from obstacles. I.e. it can be called when an instance of Drawable is in inconsistent or invalid state. I suggest add proper synchronization first.

Comment: Obstacles is type `ArrayList<Drawable>`. And how would I add a proper synchronization? I'm a bit new to java.

Comment: If your "obstacles" variable is constantly being added to while also rendering them, you need to make sure you aren't running into concurrency issues. What you'll want to do is use a CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: The proper synchronization depends on the exact internals of your Drawable. Also use CopyOnWriteArrayList. For the Drawable class, decrement of x and x2 should be atomic and synchronized with at least paint() method: 
synchronized moveToLeft() 
{ 
   x-=1; 
   x2-=1;
}. 
However, it does not make sense to have an object with x2 < 0 but this is a separate discussion. You would also want to have
synchronized getX2() { 
  return x2;
} 
and in your second thread do something like this:
if (d.getX2 == 0) {
  obstacles.remove(d);
} else {
  d.moveToLeft();
}

Comment: Alright, Peter L, I have done the moveToLeft() method, and now it seems to work alright! And I do have an `if(d.x2<0){ obstacles.remove(d);}`. Look in my second thread.

Comment: You have a check but it happens after d.x2 becomes less than 0. Is a drawable with x2 < 0 a valid object that can be painted? If so, then it's OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper synchronization depends on the exact internals of your Drawable. Also use CopyOnWriteArrayList. For the Drawable class, decrement of x and x2 should be atomic and synchronized with at least paint() method:

```
synchronized moveToLeft() { 
    x-=1; 
    x2-=1; 
}
```

However, it does not make sense to have an object with x2 < 0 but this is a separate discussion.

You would also want to have

```
synchronized getX2() { 
    return x2; 
}
```

and in your second thread do something like this:

```
if (d.getX2 == 0) { 
    obstacles.remove(d); 
} 
else { 
    d.moveToLeft(); 
}
```

The reason to do the check first is that if you do it other way around, you can and up in a situation when x2 is already -1, `obstacles.remove(d)` has not been called yet, and `d.paint()` is called. This could cause issues unless your paint() method can handle negative coordinates.